# Update UITableView when Push Notification received

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple application as RSS-reader.
How do I better organize to update feed when receiving Push Notification?

1) Call `FirstViewController` from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and update feed?

2) Send value from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to **FirstViewController**, and in **FirstViewController** update feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting `NSNotification` from AppDelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"appDidReceiveRemoteNotification"
     object:self
     userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

And listening to that notification in my ViewControllers, like this

```
- (void)remoteNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = aNotification.userInfo;

    // Update your views here
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(remoteNotificationReceived:)
                                                 name:@"appDidReceiveRemoteNotification"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```